# ReactJS DIV onClick behavior

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a `<div>` with an `onClick` handler that contains a fontawesome icon.  Clicking anywhere in the div returns the correct element ID.  Clicking on the fontawesome icon returns no ID.  In the console, clicking on the icon shows the element being clicked on is the svg itself and not the `<div>`.  How do I get around this short of writing code for both the icon AND the div?

[CodeSandBox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-cerf-7sdnh?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click through div to underlying elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-div-to-underlying-elements). i.e. just use `pointer-events: none` in the svg

Comment: As Rafael said, you must add this `<FontAwesomeIcon style={{pointerEvents: 'none'}}` and it will work

Answer (score 0):

use **e.currentTarget.id** instead of **e.target.id**

```
onClick={(e) => alert(e.currentTarget.id)}
```